# run Gitlab pipeline failed after updating gradle to 7.0.2

Tags: java, android, gradle, gitlab

i'm using android studio with java dor creating android apps, and after updating gradle to 7.0.2 pipeline in Gitlab Failing with text:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/builds/kbinform/education72-android/Edu72/build.gradle' line: 1
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Edu72'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

try change IDE settings but didnt help
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MxL2.png

Comment: Facing similar issue.. Have you solved it

Answer (score 0):

`Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle JDK`

Choose the `Android Studio Default JDK` from the drop down list

Comment: i try it but didnt help

Comment: android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        useIR = true
    }
} Try this

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: you can always downgrade by going to File > Project Structure and then change the values to Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Plugin Version to 4.2.1 and 6.9